# SIGALRM kills process

Tags: c++, unix, signals

I have a trouble with SIGALRM. I am using it to write pids of active processes every 3 seconds.
But after it fires once it kills main process. What did I do wrong?
I am also using signals to kill each of child processes after some time, I am using SIGTERM there.
It wors just fine until I add this part to list active processes. Even after killing main one the others are still going.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <map>

using namespace std;
////DARK SORROW PLACE////////////////////////////
#define CHLD_DELAY 3
std::map<pid_t, bool> pidy;
/////////////////////////////////////////////////
void sweetDreams(int sec, int nanosec)
{
        timespec ttw;
        ttw.tv_sec = sec;
        ttw.tv_nsec = nanosec;

        while( nanosleep( &ttw, &ttw) && ( errno != EINTR ) ) continue;
}
//////////////////////////////////////////////////
void ns(long int ns, timespec *ts)
{
        ts->tv_sec = (time_t)ns/1000000000;
        ts->tv_nsec = (long)(ns - ts->tv_sec*1000000000);
}
//////////////////////////////////////////////////
class Order
{
        public:
                char* table;
                int start;
                int step;
                int shift;
                long int dt;
                long int dieAfter;
};
////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void killer(int sig, siginfo_t *siginfo, void *context)
{
//      kill(siginfo->si_pid, NULL);
        _exit(0);
}
////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void carefullDad(int sig)
{
        cout << "lista zywych dzieci:\n-----------------------" << endl;
        for(auto i : pidy)
        {
                if( i.second ) cout << i.first << endl;
        }
        cout << "-----------------------" << endl;
}
////////////////////////////////////////////////////
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
        char test[] = { 't', 'e', 's', 't' };

        Order orderArr[2] = {
                {test, 0, 2, 0, 1000000000L, 10000000000L},
                {test, 1, 3, -32 , 2000000000L, 6000000000L}    
        };

        //pid_t pidArr[sizeof(orderArr) / sizeof(Order)];
        pid_t wpid;
        int status = 0;

                        struct sigevent st;
                        //      memset(&st, 0, sizeof(st));
                        st.sigev_notify = SIGEV_SIGNAL;
                        st.sigev_signo = SIGALRM;

                        struct itimerspec it;
                        //memset(&it, 0, sizeof(it));
                        it.it_value = { CHLD_DELAY,0L};
                        it.it_interval = {CHLD_DELAY,0L};

                        struct sigaction act;
                        sigemptyset(&act.sa_mask);
                        act.sa_handler = carefullDad;

                        sigaction(SIGALRM, &act, NULL);

                        timer_t timer;
                        timer_create( CLOCK_REALTIME, &st, &timer);
                        timer_settime(timer, 0, &it, NULL);

        for(Order ord : orderArr)
        {
                //              static int i = 0;
                pid_t pid = fork();

                if(pid == -1)
                {
                        cerr << "Blad!!!" << endl;
                        exit(1);
                }


                if(!pid)
                {
                        //some code here
//end rest is here
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For everyone encountering this problem in the future.
You need to set:

```
struct sigaction act;
act.sa_handler = carefullDad;
act.sa_flags = SA_RESTART;

sigaction(SIGALRM, &act, NULL);
```

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to set [`act.sa_flags`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html).

```
struct sigaction act;
sigemptyset(&act.sa_mask);
act.sa_handler = carefullDad;
act.sa_flags = 0;

sigaction(SIGALRM, &act, NULL);
```

When you set the signal handler it probably had the `SA_RESETHAND` flag set.

Comment: If my answer is not the correct answer, but yours is, then accept your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Either ignore the `SIGALRM` using [`sigprocmask()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/sigprocmask.html) or install a valid handler using [`sigaction()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/sigaction.html).

Comment: Neither this and programmerjake's solution helped :(